# CSS BugFix - Double Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an iteration of a WordPress Theme whereby a Double Scrollbar is appearing only on the homepage.  How do I remove the Double Scrollbar?  The bug can be viewed at:

http://market.rastafarianreggae.com

Is there a simple CSS BugFix to remove the Double Scrollbar on this page?

I tried using the aforementioned solution but it does not work:

```
body {
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
height: 100vh !important;
}

body{height: 100%;}
```

I expect to remove the Double Scrollbar so it appears like the following page:

http://theofficialdetermine.com

Double Scrollbar should be phased out as not an existent property.

CSS4 and CSS3 can take care of Bugs that should not exist in Modern Standards Compliant Browsers, processed by C#, C++, and C precursory websafe conditions, DOM and only can be penetrated by the most Advanced Hackers whom will work for Hague Watch

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of overflow on html:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

to:

```
html {
        font-size: 100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
```